# Get Archive with JSON feed on Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, blogger, archive

I know there is the widget for archive, but I want to create my own and add it to a page as a drop down menu.

Is there a way to get archive months and years count with JSON feed?

In this example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uo68uspy/) the code retrieve all the posts and then add their date. I removed the posts from showing, but I can't remove the day and repeated date.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function LoadTheArchive(TotalFeed) {
    var PostTitles = new Array();
    var PostURLs = new Array();
    var PostYears = new Array();
    var PostMonths = new Array();
    var PostDays = new Array();
    if ("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) {
      var PostEntries = TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
      for (var PostNum = 0; PostNum < PostEntries; PostNum++) {
        var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
        PostTitles.push(ThisPost.title.$t);
        PostYears.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(0, 4));
        PostMonths.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(5, 7));
        PostDays.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(8, 10));
        var ThisPostURL;

      }
    }
    DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles, PostURLs, PostYears, PostMonths, PostDays);
  }

  function DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles, PostURLs, PostYears, PostMonths, PostDays) {
    var MonthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var NumberOfEntries = PostTitles.length;
    for (var EntryNum = 0; EntryNum < NumberOfEntries; EntryNum++) {
      NameOfMonth = MonthNames[parseInt(PostMonths[EntryNum], 10) - 1]
      document.write("(" + NameOfMonth + " " + parseInt(PostDays[EntryNum], 10) + ", " + PostYears[EntryNum] + ")<br />");
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="http://mylifeaslucille.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive">
</script>
```

Comment: How you want the output to look like?

Comment: (June 3, 2014) (June 3, 2014) will become (June, 2014), right?

Comment: @BerozaPaul Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will:

```
function LoadTheArchive(TotalFeed) 
{    
  var resultArr = new Array();
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  if ("entry" in TotalFeed.feed)
  {        
    for (i in  TotalFeed.feed.entry)
    {
      var thisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[i];
      var dateObj = new Date(thisPost.published.$t);
      var element = "(" + months[dateObj.getMonth()] + ", " + dateObj.getFullYear() + ")<br />";
      if(resultArr.indexOf(element) == -1) resultArr.push(element);
    }
    document.write(resultArr.join('<br/>'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's exactly what I was looking for!